# Are all disposable objects instantiated within a using block disposed?

Tags: c#, vb.net, dispose, using-statement

This is a question I have asked myself many times in the past as I nested using statements 5 deep.

Reading the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) and finding no mention either way regarding *other* disposables instantiated within the block I decided it was a good Q for SO archives.

Consider this:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection())
{
    var conn2 = new SqlConnection();
}

// is conn2 disposed?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Obviously I have the answer... ;-)

The answer is no. Only the objects in the using declaration are disposed

```
[Test]
public void TestUsing()
{
    bool innerDisposed = false;
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection())
    {
        var conn2 = new SqlConnection();
        conn2.Disposed += (sender, e) => { innerDisposed = true; };
    }

    Assert.False(innerDisposed); // not disposed
}

[Test]
public void TestUsing2()
{
    bool innerDisposed = false;
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(), conn2 = new SqlConnection())
    {
        conn2.Disposed += (sender, e) => { innerDisposed = true; };
    }
    Assert.True(innerDisposed); // disposed, of course
}
```

Comment: FYI: I had the answer in the clipboard before I submitted the question.

Comment: I think it is technically possible for that thread to somehow get suspended such that `SqlConnection.Dispose()` would get called by `Component.Finalizer()` between the `conn2` variable going out of scope and your `Assert` line. There is a race condition here, is there not?

Answer (score 15):

No they are not.  Only the set of variables explicitly listed in the using clause will be automatically disposed.

Comment: So you'll need to nest your using's 6 deep :-)

Answer (score 4):

If you want the exact rules for the using statement see section 8.13 of the specification. All your questions should be clearly answered there.

Comment: @eric, thanks for the reference. I posted this Q after having sussed it out with the tests in my answer more as a public service than anything else.

Comment: @Eric: care to supply a link to the spec, for those who don't know the way to MSDN?

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't work, `conn2`  will not be disposed.
Note that multiples `using` are the only situation where I allow not using brackets for more lisibility :

```
        using (var pen = new Pen(color, 1))
        using (var brush = new SolidBrush(color))
        using (var fontM60 = new Font("Arial", 15F, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel))
        using (var fontM30 = new Font("Arial", 12F, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel))
        using (var fontM15 = new Font("Arial", 12F, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel))
        using (var fontM05 = new Font("Arial", 10F, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel))
        using (var fontM01 = new Font("Arial", 8F, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel))
        using (var stringFormat = new StringFormat())
        {
        }
```

This way, nested `using` are not a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Using causes the object in the using statement to be disposed.  If you want both of your objects to be disposed, you should rewrite this as:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection())
{
    using (var conn2 = new SqlConnection())
    {
        // use both connections here...
    }
}
```

Or, alternatively, you can use the more succinct syntax:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(), conn2 = new SqlConnection())
{
    // use both connections here...
}
```

Comment: Note that you can write this more compactly. "using(SqlConn conn1 = new SqlConn(), conn2 = new SqlConn()) { stuff }"

Comment: Also, a `using` statement rather than a block (`using(var conn=new SqlConnection())using(var conn2=new SqlConnection()){ ... }`) will be lined up nicely in Visual Studio. It won't indent the second `using`.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: I updated to show that option, too...   @Jeffrey: I tend to not do that, as StyleCop complains if you don't use braces for each statement.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Check the generated IL with ILDASM or Reflector.

Answer (score 0):

Only the variables within the `using()` will be disposed, not the actual code block.
.