# Do I need to use multiple using statements?

Tags: c#, asp.net, using-statement

**Both classes for practicality sake are disposable.**

I understand what a using block does.  But I'm not sure of all of the ways it can or needs to be used.

For example is this correct?

```
using (MyClass myClass = new MyClass(params))
{
     myClass.name = "Steve";

     SecondClass myClassSecond = new SecondClass(params);
     myClassSecond.name = "George";
     myClassSecond.msg = "Hello Man in the Yellow Hat";
}
```

Are both classes above disposed of?

Or do I need both inside a using statement?

```
using (MyClass myClass = new MyClass(params))
{
     myClass.name = "Steve";

     using (SecondClass myClassSecond = new SecondClass(params))
     {
          myClassSecond.name = "George";
          myClassSecond.msg = "Hello Man in the Yellow Hat";
     }
}
```

Is the above correct, or is there a better way to use multiple using statements?

Comment: Do those classes implement `IDisposable`? That's needed for (and the reason for) the `using`.

Comment: That depends on your implementation of `MyClass` and `SecondClass`, and also on when you need those objects to be `Dispos()`ed.

Comment: dup? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/567138/when-should-i-use-using-blocks-in-c

Comment: Related/dupes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544758/what-is-the-relationship-between-the-using-keyword-and-the-idisposable-interface http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284938/are-all-disposable-objects-instantiated-within-a-using-block-disposed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16861329/best-practice-to-avoid-multiple-disposals-with-the-using-keyword-in-c-sharp

Comment: Both would be disposable yes.  Sorry for lack of detail.

Comment: In your first example, the end of the `using` block won't magically dispose the `myClassSecond` object just because it goes out of scope. Only the object mentioned inside the `using` parenthesis is disposed. So that's incorrect. You must "nest" the `using` statements as in your last example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The `using` statement allows the programmer to specify when objects that use resources should release them.
- The object provided to the using statement must implement the `IDisposable` interface.
- This interface provides the `Dispose` method, which should release the object's resources.

Here is the sample showing use of using statement:

```
using System;
//Object of this class will be given to using hence IDisposable
class C : IDisposable        
{
    public void UseLimitedResource()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Using limited resource...");
    }

    //Dispose() Method
    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Disposing limited resource.");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (C c = new C())  //Object of Class defined above
        {
            c.UseLimitedResource();
            //Object automatically disposed before closing.
        }                            
        Console.WriteLine("Now outside using statement.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

A using statement can be exited either when:

- the end of the `using` statement is reached or
- if an exception is thrown and control leaves the statement block before the end of the statement.

> Which is proper method?

As you are saying that

> Both classes for practicality sake are disposable

., then your second approach is the appropriate one. that is:

```
using (MyClass myClass = new MyClass(params))
{
     myClass.name = "Steve";

     using (SecondClass myClassSecond = new SecondClass(params))
     {
          myClassSecond.name = "George";
          myClassSecond.msg = "Hello Man in the Yellow Hat";
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your second example is proper assuming SecondClass is indeed dispoable. If it is the first example is not correct as mySecondClass will not be disposed of. If a block of code controls the lifetime of a disposable instance it should always dispose of it.

FYI I prefer this style for disposing multiple objects in the same block as I find it more readable.

```
using (MyClass myClass = new MyClass(params))
using (SecondClass myClassSecond = new SecondClass(params))     
{
     myClassSecond.name = "George";
     myClassSecond.msg = "Hello Man in the Yellow Hat";     
}
```

Both `usings` share the same scope and Dispose in reverse order of declaration.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you.  I wasn't sure if putting everything inside one using block disposed of it all or if each item needed to be wrapped inside it's own personal disposable bubble.  Both items are indeed disposable I neglected that info.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Using blocks are handy when you are working with anything that implements `IDisposable` interface. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> [using Statement] Defines a scope, outside of which an object or objects will be disposed.

So, these is effectively an equivalent of

```
IDisposable resource = new Whatever();
try {
    // whatever
}
finally {
    resource.Dispose();
}
```

The primary advantages of `using` are:  it automatically disposes the object upon leaving the `using` block, so (1) you won't forget to do it and (2) it does the cleanup in case of exception.

Short rules:

- Anytime you open a file/database connection or create an instance of class that needs any kind of cleanup - do it in `using` block.
- If the lifetime of the object should extend the method scope - wrap it in a class, implement `IDisposable` in that class, instantiate a resource in constructor, cleanup in `Dispose`.

Answer (score 2):

A using block does not automatically dispose any child objects that implement `IDisposable`. You have to wrap inner disposables in using blocks if you want them disposed. You do, however, have a few different options for this.

You could nest multiple using blocks and they are evaluated inner-most to outer-most. There is a better way to do this, but the following example works:

```
using (MyClass myClass = new MyClass(parameters))
{
     using (SecondClass myClassSecond = new SecondClass(parameters))
     {
          myClassSecond.name = "George";
          myClassSecond.msg = "Hello Man in the Yellow Hat";
     }
}
```

If the declarations are consecutive and you don't need to do anything in between, the following syntax is more succinct:

```
using (MyClass myClass = new MyClass(parameters))
using (SecondClass myClassSecond = new SecondClass(parameters))
{
    myClassSecond.name = "George";
    myClassSecond.msg = "Hello Man in the Yellow Hat";
}
```

If you need to do something in between the declarations, then your latter example is correct:

```
using (MyClass myClass = new MyClass(parameters))
{
     myClass.name = "Steve";

     using (SecondClass myClassSecond = new SecondClass(parameters))
     {
          myClassSecond.name = "George";
          myClassSecond.msg = "Hello Man in the Yellow Hat";
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My rule of thumb is...if it implements idisposable, I use a using block.

Always better safe than sorry.

To answer your question, I would go with the second option.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is if the class has a dispose method, use using.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx

If it does not, no need.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx

I've always wished this was more in your face in the MSDN documentation.  At the end of the day, it's the classes that implement IDisposable, but really what I want is some sort of giant icon on the page that in some way says. 'Pay attention dummy! You must manage this yourself!'

Answer (score 0):

The `using` block is purely a syntactically simple way of dealing with IDisposable objects.  If you understand what `using` does, then you should understand how it can and should be used.

See this question for exactly what the `using` block is translated into:
[Uses of "using" in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75401/uses-of-using-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what those classes are and how they dispose of any resources they use.  The `using` statement is essentially the same thing as a `try/finally` block (no `catch`) which disposes of its resources in the `finally` block (by calling `.Dispose()` on the object in question).

So, first of all, if the class in question doesn't implement `IDisposable` then it's a moot point, you *can't* use it in a `using` block in that case.  If it *does* implement `IDisposable` then chances are it does so for a reason and `.Dispose()` should be called on that object when you're done with it.  In those cases, it's prudent to wrap it in a `using` block to guarantee the disposal.  (Well, "guarantee" in so much as the `finally` block will be executed.  Which is *usually* the case, unless something much worse has happened.)

Answer (score 0):

I like to implement `IDisposable` in the classes I create if they use lots of resources or if I create it as a wrapper for file handling or network resources.

In class objects that I use, I think it is important to call with a `using` block if the object in question opens files, creates network connections, etc.

Some developers will write a class that implements `IDisposable` just so they can put their code in the cleaner looking `using` block, but I think this abuses the reason for creating something that is Disposable.